# How can I create a Delphi Object Inspector at run time and use my own components with it?

Tags: delphi

Like the title says. I want to add an Object Inspector to my form at rum time, and when I click other components, it should have two way data binding with them.

That is, if I, for instance, change the `top` property of a `TPanel` in the object inspector, then the panel should move; and, if I drag the panel, the object inspector should reflect its Top & Left properties.

Of course, I mean this to work for all proprieties, and select a new component each time the user clicks one at run time.

I don't even know where to start :-(

---

[Update] I do know, however, that I would strongly prefer to use Delphi components, and nothing 3rd party

Comment: There's a jedi component for this.

Comment: Can you point me to it, please? I avoid Jedi, as they are so poorly commented, but since there seems no other option ...

Comment: There are plenty options - I wrote my own using a draw grid. Not able to share though.

Comment: I was thinking of `TValueListEditor`, but I would rather have two way data binding for free.

Comment: I'd have to do a websearch to find it. No doubt you could do just the same.

Comment: Of course. I will Google & Post here, to help others.  Fount it - http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvInspector

Comment: In features it cannot beat [ExpressVerticalGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExVerticalGrid/) (of course it's not free).

Comment: Lolxs! "Pricing starts at ***only*** $999.99"

Comment: Wow! What a deal!

Comment: I must say, it is, @Jerry. Data grid you get in that suite is excellent.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off topic here. Ask on G+ delphi devs community.

Comment: Or on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  But, I am asking if it is possible to use Delphi's own object inspector (a topic which no one has addressed so far)

Comment: I very highly doubt that you can implement the actual real object inspector in your own application. The best you can do is mimic it. Just think about the massive amount of stuff behind it - how property editors get published, how DFM gets streamed in/out, how the form designer has loads of functionality... Are you re-writing Delphi?

Comment: I was hoping that I would not have to. I was hoping/expecting that it would be available to me as a component :-(

Comment: I have seen tons of questions asking for tools or component recommendation here on SO over the years  with very high activity which where very helpful. I dont know why this policy was changed so drasticlly over time. Whats wrong with recommending a Delphi component that could help OP and others?

Comment: Policies changed. Asking for components (which I don't want, as an answer to this question) is no longer permitted. However, it ***would*** be on topic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Personally, I miss the [tag:books] tag

Comment: The main reason why we don't want tool recommendations is because the answer is almost guaranteed to be an opinion, and that could also in turn attract spammers (people who are selling the exact solution to the question). But I agree, I don't think that should be restricted. Perhaps including a `tool-recommendation` tag along with the question could be sufficient.

Comment: @kobik ask on meta

Comment: No, you cannot use the Object Inspector in your own code. It's a proprietary part of the IDE, and it is not available as source or a component. It never has been, and I highly doubt it will ever be. It's also integrated with the rest of the IDE (the Code Editor and Form Designer), neither of which are available as components either.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ken. I you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Or I could just delete the question, but leaving it might be helpful for others

Comment: I'm not sure why you seem to be expecting design-time facilities to be available to your app without having to do anything yourself.  Delphi's designers chose not to provide that facility, so if you want it you are going to have to do *something*. It's not difficult to use `GetStrProp` and `SetStrProp` in TypInfo.Pas to implement basic OI functionality, as I imagine you know already.

Comment: You can borrow one from Lazarus (I believe FreePascal has very similar, if not the same RTTI interface like Delphi).

Comment: @Victoria:  Good point.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a major effort to take the Lazarus component & try to shoehorn it into Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use the Object Inspector in your own code. It's a proprietary part of the IDE, and it is not available as source or a component. It never has been, and I highly doubt it will ever be. It's also integrated with the rest of the IDE (the Code Editor and Form Designer), neither of which are available as components either. It's functionality is contained in packages that are design-time only, and are not licensed for use outside the IDE (you can't use them in your application).

In addition, most of the property editors that are invoked by the Object Inspector are also implemented in design-time only packages that wouldn't be available to your application either.